# Take unique rows in R, but keep most common value of a column, and use hierarchy to break ties in frequency

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a data frame that looks like this:

`df <- data.frame(Set = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B"), Values=c(1,1,2,1,1,2,2))`

I want to collapse the data frame so I have one row for A and one for B. I want the `Values` column for those two rows to reflect the most common `Values` from the whole dataset.

I could do this as described here ([How to find the statistical mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/how-to-find-the-statistical-mode)), but notably when there's a tie (two values that each occur once, therefore no "true" mode) it simply takes the first value.

I'd prefer to use my own hierarchy to determine which value is selected in the case of a tie.

Comment: `df%>% group_by(Set) %>%summarise(Values = Mode(Values)[1])` where `Mode` is defined in the link you gave

Comment: Or `df %>% add_count(Values, sort = TRUE) %>% group_by(Set) %>% slice(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a data frame that defines the hierarchy, and assigns each possibility a numeric score.

```
hi <- data.frame(Poss = unique(df$Set), Nums =c(105,104))
```

In this case, `A` gets a numerical value of `105`, `B` gets a numerical score of `104` (so `A` would be preferred over `B` in the case of a tie).

Join the hierarchy to the original data frame.

```
require(dplyr)
matched <- left_join(df, hi, by = c("Set"="Poss"))
```

Then, add a frequency column to your original data frame that lists the number of times each unique `Set`-`Value` combination occurs.

```
setDT(matched)[, freq := .N, by = c("Set", "Value")]
```

Now that those frequencies have been recorded, we only need row of each `Set`-`Value` combo, so get rid of the rest.

```
multiplied <- distinct(matched, Set, Value, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Now, multiply frequency by the numeric scores.

```
multiplied$mult <- multiplied$Nums * multiplied$freq
```

Lastly, sort by `Set` first (ascending), then `mult` (descending), and use `distinct()` to take the highest numerical score for each `Value` within each `Set`.

```
check <- multiplied[with(multiplied, order(Set, -mult)), ]

final <- distinct(check, Set, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

This works because multiple instances of B (numerical score = 104) will be added together (3 instances would give B a total score in the `mult` column of 312) but whenever A and B occur at the same frequency, A will win out (105 > 104, 210 > 208, etc.).

If using different numeric scores than the ones provided here, make sure they are spaced out enough for the dataset at hand. For example, using 2 for `A` and 1 for `B` doesn't work because it requires 3 instances of B to trump A, instead of only 2. Likewise, if you anticipate large differences in the frequencies of A and B, use 1005 and 1004, since A will eventually catch up to B with the scores I used above (200 * 104 is less than 199 * 205).